# Android storage errors, cannot write files, app keeps stopping?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, 8.1-oreo, asus-zenfone-5

My Android phone runs 8.1, model ASUS Zenfone Live V. I have 15.06 GB/16 of internal storage and roughly 11/128 on an microSD card. (I checked with ASUS when I bought it, it is the max storage and speed the phone could support.)

Despite indicating more free space available, the phone has exhibited a number of weird behaviors lately.

-Camera refused to take pictures, stating `Operation failed. Insert a storage card and try again.` The microSD was never removed from device.

- Google Drive refused to download files to my device. Said it could not write to device.

-A few weeks ago a significant number of apps mysteriously stopped functioning and would crash immediately on open. After painstakingly wiping cache and data from Google Play, rebooting and reinstalling I got most of them back. A few still refused to install. One app I tried to install since then has "installed" successfully but has now begun exhibiting the same error message. App (DiskUsage) `keeps stopping` whenever you try to open it, and had had no luck opening so far. I am guessing it has a problem being unable to read or write files that is preventing it from opening.

All things point to a storage problem. Advice?